# Async await not resolving/reject the result

Tags: javascript, express, ecmascript-6, promise

Here is my sample code for async await

**controller**

```
const {addUserInterestService} = require('../services/profile.js');
const addUserInterest = async  function (req,res,next){
    try{
        let params ={
            id:req.user.userId,
            userInterests:['5bb2597ca8729e19ddaf13a8']
        };
        let result = await addUserInterestService(params);
        console.log(result);
    }catch(error){
        console.log(error);
    }

}
```

**/services/profile.js**

```
    const User = require('../models/User');
    const addUserInterestService = async (params)=>{

        console.log(params);
        return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
            User.update({
                _id:params.id,
            },{
                '$addToSet':{userInterest:{'$each':params.userInterests}}
            })
        },(err,result)=>{
            console.log("async",err,result);
            if(err){
                reject(err,null);
            }
             resolve(null,result);
        })

    }

    module.exports ={
        addUserInterestService
    }
```

But the promise not resolved here ie `console.log(result);` never returns any result.

Comment: Looks like your `addUserInterestService` does not return a Promise, but you must provide more info here

Comment: `Promise()` only takes one argument, the executor function. Your second function will never be called, nor is there a valid resolve,reject variable in that second function

Comment: I think you want to pass that `(err,result)=>{` callback to `User.update`, not to `new Promise`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function in your service is wrong. The structure of your new Promise... is off. Since you are using async/await you can do this.

```
const addUserInterestService = async (params)=>{

    const result = await User.update({
      _id:params.id,
    },{
     '$addToSet':{userInterest:{'$each':params.userInterests}}
    });

    return result;

}
```

I am guessing User.update returns a promise, so you can do.

```
const addUserInterestService = (params)=> {

  return User.update({
    _id:params.id,
  },{
    '$addToSet':{userInterest:{'$each':params.userInterests}}
  });
}
```

If you were to use new Promise...etc you can do.

```
const yourFunction = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  // do whatever
  return resolve('data');
});
```

Comment: You don't return the result of the resolve function you pass `resolve()` the data you want returned, ie `resolve('some data')`

Comment: @yBrodsky its works when I changed service to your second snippet, the controller remains the same.How this worked??

Comment: @iambatman the trick is that the function has to return a promise. Now you can return `new Promise` and that is valid. You can even do `return Promise.resolve()`and that is valid as well. Now, with this in mind, `User.update` is a function that returns a promise. So you can return that function and it works.